# Find $\sqrt 7 \pmod {2579}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, radicals

Find $\sqrt 7 \pmod {2579}$.

I think I understand how I would solve a very basic equation like this:

$x^2 = 1 \pmod 5$

make a table of all the possible solutions like this

$x=0 \implies x^2=0 \\
x=1 \implies x^2=1 \\
x=2 \implies x^2=4 \\
x=3 \implies x^2=4 \\
x=4 \implies x^2=1 \\
x=5 \implies x^2=0$

then take the ones that work. In this case $\pm 1$ and $\pm 4$ are the roots, but how do I do this with a huge prime that I can't list out all the possibilities for?

Comment: Once you find one square root, the other one will be its negative.

Comment: One possibility:  compute $\{\sqrt {7+2579n}\}$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$.  (This works very well, as it happens).

Comment: But is there really no more algorithmically efficient way?

Comment: Well, you could factor $2758=2\times 1289$ and note that the fact that $7$ has a square root means that $7^{1290}\equiv 7$.  Thus $7^{645}$ is a square root of $7$.

Comment: If you find an efficient algorithm for a large modulus (not just $2579$), then you will break Rabin's cryptosystem, and from there it's just a small step to breaking the RSA cryptosystem. So far, it hasn't been done.

Comment: There's the [Shanks-Tonelli algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm), but that's not something one would expect students to come up with on their own.

Comment: For the problem here, this theorem applies : "If $p$ is an odd prime which is $\equiv -1\pmod4$ and $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then $a^{(p+1)/4}$ is a solution to the congruence $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check that there are solutions for $x^2 \equiv 7 \bmod 2579 $ using [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion):

> If $p$ is a prime that does not divide $a$,
>   then
>   $\qquad x^2 \equiv a \bmod p$ has a solution
>   $\iff a^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \bmod p$.

We compute and see that $7^{\frac{2579-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \bmod 2579$.

Next, we find the solutions using a [theorem of Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus), which is easily checked:

> If $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, then
>   $\qquad$ the solutions of $x^2 \equiv a \bmod p$ are $x \equiv  \pm a^{\frac{p+1}{4}} \bmod p$.

This theorem applies because $2579 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and $7$ is a quadratic residue mod $2579$, as above.

So, we compute $7^{645} \equiv 88 \bmod 2579$ and so the solutions are $\pm 88 \bmod 2579$.